# Python Exponentiating Operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help me to understand the following statement?

Why this is `True`:

```
3.0 == 3
```

but this one not?

```
4 ** 0.5 != 2
```

(4**0.5 = 2.0, and according to above statement 2.0 is equal to 2), but I get `False`. WHy?

Comment: It is false that `4 ** 0.5 != 2` so the result is expected.

Comment: did you mean `==` for both? For the first example, the single `=` is an assignment operator which should fail in Python. The second example uses the *not* equals operator `!=`, which we would expect to be `False`

Comment: @Passerby why it is false?

Comment: It is true that `4 ** 0.5 == 2`, therefore it is false that `4 ** 0.5 != 2`. Can you be more specific about what part is confusing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!=` operator does the opposite of `==`.

(In your first example, you wrote `=` but I think you mean `==`.)

With `!=`, it evaluates `True` if the two numbers are **not** equal to each other, otherwise it is `False`. (Here, "equal" can include an integer and a floating point number having the same numerical value.)

So here:

```
>>> 4 ** 0.5 != 2 
False
>>> 4 ** 0.5 == 2 
True
```

Comment: A sidenote: comparing floating point numbers for equality is [not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/770830) in general case.

Comment: @bereal Yes, but I am saying only that an int and a float are not prevented from being equal merely because of having different types.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some languages, Python does not care about floats and ints when it comes to comparing. It will treat 4 and 4.0 as the exact same when comparing them to other numbers. You can debate the reliability of this feature of Python, but for the purposes of answering this question this is relevant.

Now we know this, we can see that `4 * .5` is the same is `2.0` which is the same as `2`. The actual reason the second argument is false has nothing to do with the number being a float or not, but actually to do with the operator you are using.

`==` will return true if both sides of the equation **ARE** equal, whereas `!=` will return true if both sides of the equation **ARE NOT** equal.

The second statement is using the `!=` operator and so is returning false because both sides are equal. If both sides where not equal, it would return false.

Hope this cleared things up!